# JPA - Join Two tables

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two tables, namely

```
USER_ROLE  {user_id, Role} PK {user_id, role}
ROLE_PERMISSION  {role, permission} PK {role, permission}
```

1. A User can have multiple Roles.
2. A Role can be mapped to multiple
   Permissions.

I have a entity - USER that maintains information about the User. This info is fetched via LDAP (not DB) on first login. Now, for my authorization aspects, I need to also fetch dtls on User's permissions from above mentioned tables.

So I would imagine adding attributes to my existing USER entity

```
USER {
   user_id, 
   first_name, 
   last_name,
   etc

   // Authorization
   List<String> roles;
   List<String> permissions;
}
```

Can someone pls help how I can use JPA to populate the roles and permissions Lists? Looked over internet, can't figure it out. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a USER table in your database and map it to a User object with the role and permissions.  The User object then would include additional LDAP data.

Without a USER table you have nothing to map to.

Otherwise just query for the database using native SQL queries and populate your LDAP user object yourself.

Comment: thanks James. I created two Entities for USER_ROLE and ROLE_PERMISSION and then used JPA Query to retrieve information from DB and then coded to populate the User entity. Not very elegant solution, but does the work for now.